# ProgramData folder huge size

Tags: windows, anti-virus

Some of our computers have a very large C:\ProgramData folder caused by Kaspersky Anti-Virus. It creates thousands of log files, size ranging from 200 to 300MB. I delete them every so-often but it is very tedious and counter-productive.

This issue is not limited to Kaspersky, in the past we have also used Bitdefender and Symantec and it also did this. However, it does so only on some computers, not all and I have no idea how to fix it. I have been struggling with this issue for years.

Based on my research, logs are created because the anti-virus tries to follow os hard-links and end up in continuous loop, thus the huge size of the logs. But what do I do about it?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to exclude the hard linked _"sub paths"_ from number of things that the antivirus has to control...

Comment: I'll check that and see what settings I have available but I'd like to find out WHY is it doing this. Why it works correctly on some systems and not on others.

Comment: I suppose that if you mount a remote directory, e.g. from Linux, with a circular _hard link_, some windows system are not able to see that it is an _hard link_ (and that you find again an already found inode) and continue to go down until it finish the stack length... Just a tryout